# Better performance on UITableView with Custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

i want to get rid of the lag on my UITableView, i don't know how get a better performance in my case.

1 - I have 6 different custom cells.
2 - The cells expand and collapse.
3 - when one of the expandable cells expands, other simple cells are generated underneath creating a list.

My code became quite complex when dealing with this amount of different kinds of cell. Each one of them got some different behavior and different Height.

I read on some other people questions about it, and someone said the one of the things that could improve the UITableView is to create some kind of cache on the Height when passing on this method:

*I don't know how to cache that, and i'm not sure if this will help with my problem.

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My code how it is now:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    BOOL isChild =
    currentExpandedIndex > -1
    && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
    && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        return 117;
    }

    if (currentExpandedIndex == 0) {

        if (isChild && indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex +1) {
            return 175;
        }else if (isChild){
            return 0;
        }

        if (indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex + numberOfExpandedCells + 3) {
            return 15;
        }

    }

    if (currentExpandedIndex == 2) {
        if (indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex + numberOfExpandedCells + 1) {
            return 15;
        }
    }

    if (!isChild && indexPath.row == 1) {
        return 15;
    }else if (!isChild && indexPath.row == 3){
        return 15;
    }else if (!isChild && indexPath.row == 11 + numberOfExpandedCells){
        return 100;
    }


    return 55;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    BOOL isChild =
    currentExpandedIndex > -1
    && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex
    && indexPath.row <= currentExpandedIndex + [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count];


    if (!isChild) {

        static NSString *PanelCellIdentifier = @"PanelCell";
        static NSString *ParentCellIdentifier = @"ParentCell";
        static NSString *TutorialCellIdentifier = @"TutorialCell";

        if (indexPath.row == 0) {

            DSPanelTableViewCell *cell = (DSPanelTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PanelCellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSPanelTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }

            [cell configurePanelCellFor:user.recomendacoes with:user.pontos expanded:currentExpandedIndex withCalc:calc];

            return cell;

        }else{


            DSMealTableViewCell *cell = (DSMealTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ParentCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSMealTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            int topIndex = (currentExpandedIndex > -1 && indexPath.row > currentExpandedIndex)
            ? indexPath.row - [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] count]
            : indexPath.row;

            [cell configureMealCellWithTitles:titlesArray subTitles:subtitlesArray points:pointsArray minMax:minMax forIndex:topIndex];

            if (currentExpandedIndex == 0) {
                if (indexPath.row == 2 + numberOfExpandedCells){
                    CGRect frame = cell.title.frame;
                    frame.origin.y += 8;
                    cell.title.frame = frame;
                    cell.subTitle.hidden = YES;
                }
            }else if (indexPath.row == 2 || indexPath.row == 9 + numberOfExpandedCells) {

                CGRect frame = cell.title.frame;
                frame.origin.y += 8;
                cell.title.frame = frame;
                cell.subTitle.hidden = YES;

            }else{
               cell.subTitle.hidden = NO;
            }


            if (indexPath.row == 10 + numberOfExpandedCells) {
                DSTutorialTableViewCell *cell = (DSTutorialTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TutorialCellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSTutorialTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
                }
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
                cell.delegate = self;
                cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;
                return cell;
            }


            if ((currentExpandedIndex == 0 && indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex + numberOfExpandedCells + 3) ||
                (currentExpandedIndex == 2 && indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex + numberOfExpandedCells + 1) ||
                (indexPath.row == 1 || indexPath.row == 3 || indexPath.row == 11 + numberOfExpandedCells)) {
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
                cell.hidden = YES;
            }else{
                cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                cell.hidden = NO;
            }

            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            return cell;
        }

    }else{

        static NSString *PanelCellIdentifier = @"PanelCell";
        static NSString *ButtonCellIdentifier = @"ButtonCell";
        static NSString *ChildCellIdentifier = @"ChildCell";


        if (indexPath.row == currentExpandedIndex +1 ) {

            if (currentExpandedIndex == 0) {

                DSPanelInfoTableViewCell *cell = (DSPanelInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PanelCellIdentifier];
                if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSPanelInfoTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
                }

                [cell configurePanelInfoCellWithPontos:user.pontos withCalc:calc];

                return cell;
            }

            DSButtonsTableViewCell *cell = (DSButtonsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ButtonCellIdentifier];
            if (cell == nil) {
                cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSButtonsTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            }
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            cell.delegate = self;
            cell.cellIndex = indexPath.row;
            return cell;
        }


        DSItemTableViewCell *cell = (DSItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChildCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DSItemTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        }


        if (currentExpandedIndex == 0) {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            cell.hidden = YES;
            return cell;
        }

        NSDictionary* dict = [[subItems objectAtIndex:currentExpandedIndex] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - currentExpandedIndex - 1];
        [cell configureItemCellWithDetails:dict];

        return cell;
    }

}
```

I know.. wow this is too much code to process a UITableView... but i don't know how to improve it.
This code works fine, but the tableview's performance is bad. Can anyone help ?

Comment: An educated guess: maybe you haven't set `reuseIdentifier` for your cells in .xib? If this is not the case, then use a profiler (Instruments) to determine which part of code is responsible for the poor performance.

Comment: It worked... i wasn't setting the identifier on the xib... thanks a lot !! XD

Comment: Good to know that, I turned my comment into an answer then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `reuseIdentifier` in .xib file for your cells. Otherwise they won't be reused and performance will drop.

Answer (score -1):

Your code is difficult to read and a bit complex...

You can simplify it a lot... try to separate the cell using function...

This is an elegant way to do that I use all the time..
Here's only working on create multiples custom cells, there aren't any code for calculate the height of the cells.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    /*
       Call a function to create all custom cells.
       Send the tableview and the indexPath to this function.
       So, your code will be clean and easy to read an maintenance =D
       DON'T forget to change the height of each cell
       Create all the if you want to call the function for creating their cells
    */
    if (indexPath.row < 3){
        return [self createACustomCell1:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    }else{
        return [self createACustomCell2:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    }
}


//*************
//  Create CUSTOM CELL 1
//*************
-(UITableViewCell *)createACustomCell1:(UITableView *)anTableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CUSTOMCELL_1  = @"CUSTOMCELL_1";

    CustomCell_1 *cell = [anTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_1];
    if (!cell){
    [anTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CUSTOMCELL_1
                                          bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_1];
        cell = [anTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_1];
    }

    // Cell customization above 
    return cell;
}


//*************
//  Create CUSTOM CELL 2
//*************
-(UITableViewCell *)createACustomCell2:(UITableView *)anTableView indexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CUSTOMCELL_2  = @"CUSTOMCELL_2";

    CustomCell_2 *cell = [anTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_2];
    if (!cell){
    [anTableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:CUSTOMCELL_2
                                          bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_2];
        cell = [anTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CUSTOMCELL_2];
    }

    // Cell customization above


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It has been answered already, it was one little detail i've forgotten, but thanks anyway. I agree when you say the code is complex (it does a complex thing as well), but, is not hard to read at all, just create methods for each cell to be created in a different function doesn't help the app to get a better performance.